# HQL: get a list where a join contains nulls

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I have three objects.

```
public class ParentClass
{
public virtual Guid ParentClassId { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
public virtual Guid ChildId { get; set; }
public virtual ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
public virtual Guid RecordId { get; set; }
public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

ParentClass and a collection of Child is added into the database by an outside service.  A service will run that will occasionally look for any of Child that need to be processed and bring back a list of ParentClass, as each Child in ParentClass should be processed together.

I want to write a HQL query to select the distinct parent of all Children where no Records's have a foreign key to them.  Currently, I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Parent FROM Child c LEFT JOIN Record r WHERE r is null
```

But I get an error saying a Path is expected.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show what would your SQL query would look like (if you were to do this in SQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a subquery, eg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Parent FROM Child c WHERE NOT EXISTS(FROM Record r WHERE r.Child = c)
```